# Using Cookie in Laravel 4

Tags: php, cookies, laravel, laravel-4

When I create a cookie or store a value in a session, I can't access them later. It seems they're removed already.

My question is can I use pure PHP code to handle cookies and sessions in Laravel?

For now I use this code for Laravel:

```
Cookie::make('test-cookie', 'test data', 30);
```

But without success.

Comment: What is your question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to return your cookie with a response. From Laravel's documentation:

```
$response = Response::make('Hello World');
$response->withCookie(Cookie::make('name', 'value', $minutes));
```